Easy way to remove added ActivityListener
In the decompiled external configuration library that I use in my project, I see the following statement:
ActivitySource.AddActivityListener(listenerInstance);

How can I remove it from my project without editing the original library?
I tried:
System.Diagnostics.ActivitySource.RemoveAllActivityListeners();

...but this method does not exist.
